# Characterisation of a closed subspace with respect to the initial topology induced by a subspace of the algebraic dual space.

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

There is the following characterisation of a closed subspace:

> Let $X$ be a linear space equipped with the initial topology induced by some subspace $X'$ of the algebraic dual space $X^{\#}$, and let $A \subset X$. Then the following are equivalent:
>
> (i) $A$ is a closed subspace of $X$.
>
> (ii) For each $x \in A^c$, there exists an $f_x \in X'$ such that $f_x (x) = 1$ and $A \subseteq \text{ker}(f_x)$.

I have difficulties in showing both implications.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Is $X'$ a separating family of functionals (i.e. if $0\neq x\in X,$ then there is some $f\in X'$ with $f(x)\neq0$)?

Comment: Not necessarily I think. It is only given that $X' \subset X^{\#}$ is a subspace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(i)\implies(ii)$ This is a consequence of (one of the corollaries to) the Hahn-Banach theorem.

$(ii)\implies(i)$ Observe that 
$$ A=\bigcap_{x\in A^c}\ker(f_x). $$
Thus $A$ is the intersection of closed subspaces, hence it is a closed subspace.

Comment: Thanks! In fact, X is locally convex with respect to the initial topology induced by $X'$. The subbasis of the topology on $X$ is given by
$$ \{ f^{-1} (B) \; | \; f \in X', B \subset \mathbb{F} \}, $$ where $B$ denotes an open ball in $\mathbb{F}$.

Comment: @user342207 In that case, let me edit

Comment: I have difficulties showing that $$ \bigcap_{x\in A^c}\ker(f_x) \subseteq A. $$ Could you please give me a hint?

Comment: @user342207  Suppose there is some $y\in\bigcap_{x\in A^c}\ker(f_x) $ with $y\notin A$.  Then $y\in A^c$, and $y\notin\ker(f_{y'})$, contradiction.